# Football nested JSON object

Tags: json

I'm trying to extract the result object which contains the goals for both the home team  and the away team. How can I get the integer values for both these items, and then assign them to the array list?

```
"fixtures": [
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/fixtures/150840"
        },
        "soccerseason": {
          "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/426"
        },
        "homeTeam": {
          "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/62"
        },
        "awayTeam": {
          "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/73"
        }
      },
      "date": "2016-08-13T14:00:00Z",
      "status": "FINISHED",
      "matchday": 1,
      "homeTeamName": "Everton FC",
      "awayTeamName": "Tottenham Hotspur FC",
      "result": {
        "goalsHomeTeam": 1,
        "goalsAwayTeam": 1
      }
]
```

My Code:

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            JSONArray ja = jsonObj.getJSONArray("fixtures");

            matchList.clear();  //Clears the ArrayList.
            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++)  //iterating in JSONArray
            {
                JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                int matchDay = jo.getInt(MATCH_DAY);
                String homeTeamName = jo.getString(HOME_TEAM_NAME);
                String awayTeamName = jo.getString(AWAY_TEAM_NAME);
                String date = jo.getString(DATE);
                JSONObject result = jo.getJSONObject(RESULT);
                int goalsHometeam = result.getInt(GOALS_HOME);
                int goalsAwayTeam =  result.getInt(GOALS_AWAY);
                String status = jo.getString(STATUS);

                Match match = new Match();

                match.setMatchday(matchDay);
                match.setHomeTeamName(homeTeamName);
                match.setAwayTeamName(awayTeamName);
                match.setDate(date);
                match.setGoalsHometeam(goalsHometeam);
                match.setGoalsAwayTeam(goalsAwayTeam);
                match.setStatus(status);
```

Comment: `self`, `soccerseason`, `homeTeam`, and `awayTeam` are subobjects of `_links`

Answer (score 0):

Your `JSON` is `not a valid JSON`.

[image]

updated `JSON Structure` :

```
{
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/fixtures/150840"
        },
        "soccerseason": {
          "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/426"
        },
        "homeTeam": {
          "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/62"
        },
        "awayTeam": {
          "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/73"
        }
      },
      "date": "2016-08-13T14:00:00Z",
      "status": "FINISHED",
      "matchday": 1,
      "homeTeamName": "Everton FC",
      "awayTeamName": "Tottenham Hotspur FC",
      "result": {
        "goalsHomeTeam": 1,
        "goalsAwayTeam": 1
      }
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/23hg6zk4/)

```js
var fixtures = {
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/fixtures/150840"
        },
        "soccerseason": {
          "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/426"
        },
        "homeTeam": {
          "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/62"
        },
        "awayTeam": {
          "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/73"
        }
      },
      "date": "2016-08-13T14:00:00Z",
      "status": "FINISHED",
      "matchday": 1,
      "homeTeamName": "Everton FC",
      "awayTeamName": "Tottenham Hotspur FC",
      "result": {
        "goalsHomeTeam": 1,
        "goalsAwayTeam": 1
      }
};

var res = Object.keys(fixtures.result).map(item => { return fixtures.result[item] });

console.log(res);
```